# Repair GRUB bootloader for multiboot system

Tags: linux, grub, linux-mint, bootloader, ubuntu-12.04

I have two hard disks – one a 1TB and the other a 250 GB. I installed the OSes in the following order:

- Windows 7 on the first hard disk (1 TB)
- After that Kubuntu 12.04 on a partition (`/dev/sdb7`) on the second hard disk (250 GB)
- The second drive also contains an NTFS partition.

Now, kubuntu's bootloader was installed on the second hard drive's MBR (and successfully detected Windows 7). So, whenever I wanted to load Windows I used to select the first hard disk from the BIOS boot menu and the second hard disk whenever I wanted to load kubuntu. I know I could have set the second hard disk as the default drive, still I prefered this method.

The problem started when I installed Linux Mint 13 on the second hard disk (`/dev/sdb3`) and overwrote kubuntu's original MBR. Now, the GRUB just detects Mint and Windows. The MBR on the 1 TB hard disk is untouched.

Is there a way I can modify the MBR on the second hard disk now so that it will show kubuntu and Mint both?

Answer (score 1):

What usually works for me, is to boot into the "hidden" operational system (Kubuntu in your case) by using e.g. [super grub](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/), and from that system I'd run sudo update-grub. The other system should detect your Mint, and update grub accordingly.